# HTML a tag inside svg tag stays in black color

Tags: html, css

I want to make a circle that has text in it (that is clickable). It works... it is clickable... but the text color changes to black when I click it. And then it won't turn back to the color I want it to be.

```
<svg>
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="grey" />
    <text style="text-decoration: none; color: green;" x="50" y="50"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: green;" href="#">hei</a></text>
</svg>
```

The reason for why I have written text-decoration and color in both the text and a tag is because I've tried it with both of them, and none of them works.

Comment: Do you have a specific purpose by using the SVG element?
For my understanding it is a HTML5 element that should be styled according to an XML element. Therefore you cannot style it with ordinary CSS. You should either go the XML way or the HTML/CSS way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fill` instead of color as it is a [SVG text node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)

See snippet below

```css
text a {
 /* fill:red;*/
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" fill="grey" />
    <text x="50" y="50"><a style="text-decoration: none; fill: green;" href="#">hei</a></text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @NitroFray however it works in the snippet. You may have other issue in your css

Comment: Oh, lol, it worked now... I can't believe that I forgot to check fill in the a tag... anyway thx.

Comment: @NitroFray don't forget to accept the answer if it works!;)